# How to save 1 information to 2 tables on Django

Tags: python, django, backend

How can I save 1 information to 2 tables on Django, when user register he entres his username, and I need to save this username in table "users" and in table "authors", how can i realize it?

`views.py`

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nick = request.POST.get('nick')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        ppassword = request.POST.get('ppassword')

        if password == ppassword:

            new_user = User.objects.create_user(nick, email, password)
            new_user.nick = nick
            new_user.email = email

            new_user.save()

            return redirect('../login/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Пароль и повтор пароля не совподают")

    return render(request, 'main/register.html')
```

`models.py`

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    slug = slug = models.SlugField(max_length=400, unique=True, blank=True)
    bio = HTMLField()
    profile_pic = ResizedImageField(size=[50, 80], quality=100, upload_to="authors", default=None, null=True,
                                    blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def num_posts(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(user=self).count()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.username)
        super(Author, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to double the information in db (and you shouldn't). Better make a FK relation from Author to User, and create the Author in register function.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    // ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="author", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nick = request.POST.get('nick')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        ppassword = request.POST.get('ppassword')

        if password == ppassword:

            new_user = User.objects.create_user(nick, email, password)
            new_user.nick = nick
            new_user.email = email

            new_user.save()

            author = Author.opjects.create(
                            user=new_user,
                            // other fields) 

            return redirect('../login/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Пароль и повтор пароля не совподают")

    return render(request, 'main/register.html')
```

Comment: I used your code, and got error:
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username
`